# Start up recovery can't fix, stuck on startup repair

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

The problem first started after I used something called "windows clean up". When that had finished, I put my laptop into hibernation mode. In the process of doing so, it became black screen (The display was still lit but black). I tried "ctrl+alt+del", but there was no response. I waited some additional time but there was still no change. I then hit then power button but there was no response too. Because of that I held the power button for a hard shutdown.

After doing the above, I always find myself stuck at start up recovery menu. The problem with this is that I get a message saying "start up repair has tried several times but still can't determine the cause of the problem".

My system is an Asus Core i3 running Windows 7 64 bit.

This is what I have done so far:

Startup Error Report

```
problem signature:
problem event name :
problem signature 1: StartUpRepairOffline 
problem signature 2: 6.1.7600.16385
problem signature 3: 6.1.7600.16385
problem signature 4: unknown
problem signature 5: 21199264
problem signature 6: AutoFailover
problem signature 7: CorruptRegistry
os version : 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
locale id : 1033
```

I have already tried `chkds`, and `chkdsk /f` on my windows os partition (G:) but reports no bad sectors "0 kb in bad sector". There is an error displayed, "failed to transfer logged message to the even lo with status 50"  I am unable to copy a detailed report, as I am unable can't to copy the error text.

```
FixMbr and FixBoot success
ScanOS Successfully scanned windows installations. .
total identified windows installation:0
the operation complete successfully
```

System restore has not helped.

I don't know what to do.
Please lend your strength.

I have already search on the internet but I can't find a solution to fix my problem. I don't have another working PC, so I'm borrowing my friend's laptop. I also don't have another hard drive to back up onto.

I can't go into safe mode, last good, or normal boot. I always get put to the startup repair screen.

Comment: "CorruptRegistry" -> Reinstall Windows

Comment: any way for me to repair it manually without re-install? i using fedora live disk to open my hardisk partition, and it say status "OK".... and i don't found corrupt/bad sector tooo...... i can't get into safe mode, last good mode, normal mode....etc... always stuck on startup repair screen..... reinstall still hard and hurt

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: i lost software, configuration, environment path[many and i already forget what i set and how to set it ex:java,node.js,android,genymotion,r, ,,,,, what again....], session manager, etc.....  i will wait for some time.... re-install is super duper very last resort

Comment: You have backups, right?

Comment: hmmmm, don't have device to back-up..... now i use live Fedora to access my laptop, browsing internet, and thinking what file in "c:/users" that i need to copy to another partition, and some data[document, movie, picture,audio etc file non system] i can't copy because  don't have a freespace....

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you can backup your user files(documents, pictures) to external media!

In "\Windows\system32\config\RegBack" there are backup copies of system registry hives (DEFAULT, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE, SYSTEM).

As a last resort before reinstalling Windows copy these files to 
"\Windows\system32\config".

It would be better if you first rename the files (DEFAULT, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE, SYSTEM) in "\Windows\system32\config" to corresponding_file_name.BAK

This procedure would bring the system registry to an older state so some software you installed recently may not be available (may not function properly) also if you changed some Windows settings they would be set to a previous state.

Comment: thanks. already try that too before. but still end up on start up repair screen----- thanks to all answer.. i reinstall my windows because i really need my laptop and i installing windows without formatting my windows partition.....